# How to check if an object is JavaScript object in Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

Is there a secure way of doing this?

I tried

```
typeof {};
typeof someJavaObject;
```

But in both cases I am getting 'object'. I think this behavior is expected since all java objects are ScriptableObject, am I right?

So, then, how do I figure out if a variable refers to a javascript object (or a Java one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `someJavaObject instanceof java.lang.Object`.

I would write a function though so it's clear what you're doing:

```
function isJavaObject(obj) {
    return obj instanceof java.lang.Object;
}
```